# Examples of Visual Studio "GoTo Definition" for custom language?

Tags: visual-studio, dsl

Are there examples of implementing a custom language extension (textual DSL) in Visual Studio 2017, with support for "GoTo Definition"?  It seems there is not enough flexibility in the `VisualStudioWorkspace` to support generic symbol tables (i.e., not C# or VB).

There is support for GoTo Definition for custom languages in [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/language-support#_show-definitions-of-a-symbol).

The support for "GoTo Definition" in [Java](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/integrate/ide/extensions/develop_extensions/add_new_language) for Visual Studio, in `JavaIntellisenseController.GoToSourceImpl()`, doesn't seem to actually resolve Java symbols.

[Roslyn](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation/RoslynVisualStudioWorkspace.cs,175) implements the abstract method `Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.VisualStudioWorkspace.TryGoToDefinition()`, but this API uses types specific to .NET languages, like [`Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ISymbol`](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Symbols/ISymbol.cs).

Is there another way, maybe using a custom `Workspace` class?

Comment: @HansPassant The Workspace is a natural place to keep a symbol table that spans multiple documents and projects, but I don't know how to hook into the Workspace class.  I was hoping to find an example.

Answer (score 1):

Building a [language server](https://langserver.org/) looks like it will soon be a useful alternative to building custom language support in Visual Studio from scratch.  Visual Studio is getting a new experimental facility for language servers, available in preview [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/adding-an-lsp-extension).  Examples of language servers built in C# are available from [Microsoft](https://github.com/Microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/tree/master/LanguageServerProtocol) and [OmniSharp](https://github.com/OmniSharp/csharp-language-server-protocol/).  The latter looks like a general scaffold for building language servers in C#.

This answer doesn't point to a working open source example of a custom language implementation for Visual Studio with "GoTo Definition" support, as asked, but it provides a more workable alternative.  The question about re-using the `VisualStudioWorkspace` is moot; a language server maintains its own workspace state.

Language servers don't implement syntax highlighting.  VS Code uses a [TextMate grammar](http://manual.macromates.com/en/language_grammars) for syntax highlighting.  But there are [hints](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/585) that more refined syntax highlighting will be available from the [language server protocol](https://github.com/Microsoft/language-server-protocol) in the future.

Comment: The [LSP wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/language-server-protocol/wiki) points to implementations and SDK's.

Comment: AFAIK, LSP support for Visual Studio is only available in "Open Folder" mode.